# ajaxSetup beforeSend only being called the first time button is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am using ASP.Net MVC and jQuery 1.8.2

I have a form with a button that calls this javascript when it is clicked:

```
$(function () {
    $('#SearchButton').click(function () {
        var data = $('#FilterDefinition :input').serialize() + "&PageNumber=1";
        $.post('@Url.Action("Search")', data, LoadContentCallback);
        $("#SearchResults").show();
    });
});
```

This calls an MVC Controller Action which returns a PartialViewResult

On the Layout page I have the following JavaScript code:

```
//Add a custom header to all AJAX Requests
        $(document).ready(function () {                
            $.ajaxSetup({
                beforeSend: function(xhr) {
                    debugger;
                    if ($('[name=__RequestVerificationToken]').length) {
                        var token = $('[name=__RequestVerificationToken]').val();
                        xhr.setRequestHeader('__RequestVerificationToken', token);
                    }
                }
            });
        });
```

When the button is clicked for the first time, the beforeSend function is called correctly.  However, if the button is clicked more than once (for example they change the search criteria and search again) then the beforeSend function never gets called again and the validate anti-forgery fails.

I tried using the ajaxSend event instead and I got the same results.

Any help is solving this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: It happens in Chrome, Firefox, and IE.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out the problem was that the partial view that was being rendered was referencing a different version of jQuery.  I removed this reference and everything started working correctly.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid using $.ajaxSetup if possible. I would just setup your beforeSend in the actual POST request.

Comment: It isn't very practical to go back through hundreds of POST calls throughout the entire application to add this to every single one of them.